# Error De-serializing XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have the class structure like:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "DocumentElement", Namespace = "")]
public class Message
{
    public Person person;
    public class Person
    {
        public int Age{ get; set; } // readonly
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I pass the following xml to the class to deserialize:

```
<DocumentElement>
 <person>
  <Age>13</Age>
  <Name>My Name</Name>
 </person>
</DocumentElement>
```

No matter I put the xml header  on or off, always returns the same error:

> there is an error in xml document (5, 4)

with the following code:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Message));
try
{
    Message postMsg = (Message)serializer.Deserialize(InputStream);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Anyone please help to have a check

Comment: Works fine for me... Please show your deserialization code.

Comment: XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Message));
                serializer.UnknownNode += serializer_UnknownNode;
       
                    Message xmlMessage = (Message)serializer.Deserialize(InputStream);

Comment: You should [edit] your question, not put code in a comment.

Comment: Are you reading from a file? What is the encoding of the file?

Comment: reading from a http stream

Comment: Are you sure that's all you're getting from the HTTP stream? Can you convert it to a string and see exactly what's in it?

Comment: Yes, 100% sure! and I've already converted to string, exactly the same

Comment: @user3435230, I edited your question because I thought you had trouble formatting the XML; does the HTTP response actually contain `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>`, or did you write them yourself?

Comment: Well using that string, it works perfectly for me. Here's an example of it working https://ideone.com/6JFFu0

Comment: @Thomas: no, the response doesn't contain &lt; just had problem on formatting xml.